# Non-type template param vs direct usage (`incomplete type used in nested name specifier`)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, tuples, template-meta-programming

I observe somewhat strange behavior which I don't entirely understand, and was hoping someone can explain what's going on.

Here is "minimal" example adopted from the actual code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

namespace so {
// ---- //
template <typename _t_source_,
          typename _t_destination_,
          bool _t_value = 
            std::is_constructible<_t_destination_, _t_source_>::value> 
struct is_creatable_1 : 
  std::integral_constant<bool, _t_value> {
};

template <typename _t_source_,
          typename _t_destination_>
struct is_creatable_2 : 
  std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_constructible<_t_destination_, 
                                                     _t_source_>::value> {
};

template <typename ..._tp_>
class _foo_ {
  private:
    using _pack_ = std::tuple<std::vector<_tp_>...>;

  private:
    _pack_ pack_;

  private:
    template <std::size_t ..._t>
    auto
    _init(std::index_sequence<_t...>) -> void {
      using _expander_ = int[];
      _expander_{int{}, 
                 (static_cast<void>(std::get<_t>(pack_).resize(_t + 2)),
                  int{})...};
    }
  public:
    _foo_() {
      _init(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<_pack_>::value>{});
    }
};

class _bar_ {
  private:
    using _value_ = std::string;

  private:
    _value_ value_{};

  public:
    _bar_() = default;

    template <typename _t_value_ = _value_,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                !std::is_constructible<_bar_, _t_value_ &&>::value &&
                !is_creatable_1<_t_value_ &&, _bar_>::value &&
// Fails ==>    !is_creatable_2<_t_value_ &&, _bar_>::value &&
                true
              >::type>
    inline explicit
    _bar_(_t_value_ &&)
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<_value_, _t_value_ &&>::value) {
    }
};
// ---- //
} // `so` namespace. 

auto
main() -> int {
  so::_foo_<so::_bar_> t{};
}
```

The commented line fails with rather long message (see for yourself [on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/CR7h9m)) with
`error: incomplete type ‘std::is_constructible<so::_bar_, so::_bar_&&>’ used in nested name specifier struct is_creatable_2`.

It seems to me, the question more or less boils down to the following:

in the given context, what is the difference between

```
template <typename _t_source_,
          typename _t_destination_,
          bool _t_value = 
            std::is_constructible<_t_destination_, _t_source_>::value> 
struct is_creatable_1 : 
  std::integral_constant<bool, _t_value> {
};
```

and

```
template <typename _t_source_,
          typename _t_destination_>
struct is_creatable_2 : 
  std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_constructible<_t_destination_, 
                                                     _t_source_>::value> {
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Clang accepts the code:[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7762a7725a513eca)

Comment: `is_creatable_1` allow sto bypass the check (as `is_creatable_1<std::string, int, true>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for pointing out that the `clang` compiles it. Sorry, what is "sto"?

Comment: *"allows to"* with space typo.

Comment: lol. I thought it was some kind of acronym, like "Standard Template O-something"